Angular - Validator not working when pasting the value to control with Phone Directive to format value
We are using Angular 17 along with Reactive forms in our project.
We have written a custom directive which formats the output to US phone number format 111-222-3333.
What we are seeing is that when someone tries to copy a number into the field - the field gets formatted, but the validator is still saying it is not valid.
HTML Code:
 <input matInput phoneFormatterDirective placeholder="Enter Phone" formControlName="phone"
                class="inputEntry">

Typescript Code:
phone: new FormControl(null, [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$')])

Custom Directive Code:
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[phoneFormatterDirective]'
})
export class PhoneFormatterDirective {

  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    console.log(input.value);
    let trimmed = input.value
      .replaceAll('-','')
      .replaceAll('(','')
    .replaceAll(')','')
    .replaceAll(/\s+/g, '');
    if (trimmed.length > 12) {
      trimmed = trimmed.substr(0, 12);
    }
    let numbers = [];
    numbers.push(trimmed.substr(0,3));
    if(trimmed.substr(3,2)!=="")
      numbers.push(trimmed.substr(3,3));
    if(trimmed.substr(6,3)!="")
      numbers.push(trimmed.substr(6,4));

    input.value = numbers.join('-');
    console.log(numbers.join("-"));
  }
}

Let's say I am trying to paste (555) 123-1234 - the value gets formatted to 555-123-1234, but the input says it is still invalid.
It would be valid if I deleted one character and then wrote it manually - which is a kind of strange behavior.


Currently, you are setting the formatted value to HtmlInputElement's value, but it is not reflected in the form control's state.
I would suggest grabbing and setting the value from/to NgControl in order to update the form control's state.
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[phoneFormatterDirective]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class PhoneFormatterDirective {
  constructor(public control: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const input = this.control.control!;

    console.log(input.value);
    let trimmed = input.value
      .replaceAll('-', '')
      .replaceAll('(', '')
      .replaceAll(')', '')
      .replaceAll(/\s+/g, '');
    if (trimmed.length > 12) {
      trimmed = trimmed.substr(0, 12);
    }

    let numbers = [];
    numbers.push(trimmed.substr(0, 3));

    if (trimmed.substr(3, 2) !== '') numbers.push(trimmed.substr(3, 3));
    if (trimmed.substr(6, 3) != '') numbers.push(trimmed.substr(6, 4));

    input!.setValue(numbers.join('-'), { emitEvent: false });
  }
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

This seems to have done the trick. That totally makes sense now, I have to manipulate the NgControl in order for the reactive  forms to pick it up. I have a question on emitEvent, is that really needed and why?

Hi, the emitEvent is optional, this aims not to fire the value change event if you subscribe to this.form.controls["phone"].valueChanges observable: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setvalue
